# Pythonを使って3次元配列の組み合わせを求めることについて

Tags: python

Pythonを使って3次元配列の組み合わせを求めることに困っています。

liの番号はそれぞれli1～3に対応しており、結果を表す3次元配列lifinを求めたいです。

```
start=0
goal=10
li1=[2,3]
li2=[5,7]
li3=[8,9]

li=[[1],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

始点(start)は0、終点(goal)は10を表しています。

例えばli[1]=[1,2]ですが、これはstart→li1→li2→goalを表していて,結果として以下の様なものが導出して欲しいです。    
 [[0,2,5,10],[0,2,7,10],[0,3,5,10],[0,3,7,10]]

最終的に、以下のlifinの様な結果を求めたいです。

```
lifin=[[[0,2,10],[0,3,10]],
       [[0,2,5,10],[0,2,7,10],[0,3,5,10],[0,3,7,10]],
       [[0,5,8,10],[0,5,9,10],[0,7,8,10],[0,7,9,10]],
       [[0,2,5,8,10],[0,2,5,9,10],[0,2,7,8,10],[0,2,7,9,10],[0,3,5,8,10],[0,3,5,9,10],[0,3,7,8,9,10],[0,3,7,9,10]]]
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

前処理

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> start=0
>>> goal=10
>>> M={}
>>> M[1]=[2,3]
>>> M[2]=[5,7]
>>> M[3]=[8,9]
>>> li=[[1],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

回答

```
>>> result = []
>>> for x in li:
...     r = []
...     for y in product(*[M[k] for k in x]):
...         r.append([start]+list(y)+[goal])
...     result.append(r)
... 
>>> result
[[[0, 2, 10], [0, 3, 10]], [[0, 2, 5, 10], [0, 2, 7, 10], [0, 3, 5, 10], [0, 3, 7, 10]], [[0, 5, 8, 10], [0, 5, 9, 10], [0, 7, 8, 10], [0, 7, 9, 10]], [[0, 2, 5, 8, 10], [0, 2, 5, 9, 10], [0, 2, 7, 8, 10], [0, 2, 7, 9, 10], [0, 3, 5, 8, 10], [0, 3, 5, 9, 10], [0, 3, 7, 8, 10], [0, 3, 7, 9, 10]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

おそらく、`itertools.product`を探されていたのだと思います。
`itertools.product`を使えば、あとは簡単ですので、ループなどで組み立てるだけです。

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import itertools

start = [0]
goal = [10]
num_lists = [
        None,
        [2, 3],
        [5, 7],
        [8, 9]
        ]
chose_lists = [
        [1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        ]

result = []

for chose_list in chose_lists:
    chosen_num_lists = [num_lists[x] for x in chose_list]
    result.append([
        start + list(x) + goal
        for x in itertools.product(*chosen_num_lists)])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

結果

```python
[[[0, 2, 10], [0, 3, 10]],
 [[0, 2, 5, 10], [0, 2, 7, 10], [0, 3, 5, 10], [0, 3, 7, 10]],
 [[0, 5, 8, 10], [0, 5, 9, 10], [0, 7, 8, 10], [0, 7, 9, 10]],
 [[0, 2, 5, 8, 10],
  [0, 2, 5, 9, 10],
  [0, 2, 7, 8, 10],
  [0, 2, 7, 9, 10],
  [0, 3, 5, 8, 10],
  [0, 3, 5, 9, 10],
  [0, 3, 7, 8, 10],
  [0, 3, 7, 9, 10]]]
```